# How do I get a graphic display of my current KDE 5 configuration to help send a report?

Tags: configuration, kde5

How do I get a graphic display of my current KDE 5 configuration to help send a report?
One with a graphic display which allows me to copy a text report for mailing will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kinfocenter` command pops up a screen which details the system configuration. It doesn't have a copy to file option, but it gives enough details to be typed up and sent.